# Returning results to the Controller not in the ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, model-view-controller

I have a VS2012, MVC 4, Entity Framework 4.0 project for surveys.  I'm having difficulty coming up with a way to get the results back to my controller.  Most of the answers will be from dropdownlists, one for each question. I'm using a view to flatten out the tables for a concise object with all the information I need in my view.  The SQL view looks like this:

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT 
    Questionaires.QuestionaireKey, 
    Questionaires.QuestionaireName, 
    Sections.SectionKey,
    Sections.SectionName, 
    QuestionaireSections.DefaultSequence AS QAS_Sequence, 
    Questions.QuestionKey, 
    Questions.Question, 
    SectionQuestions.DefaultSequence AS SQ_Sequence,
    QuestionTypes.QuestionTypeKey, 
    QuestionTypes.QuestionTypeName, 
    AnswerListCodes.AnswerListCodeKey, 
    AnswerListCodes.AnswerListCodeName, 
    QuestionAnswerListCodes.DefaultSequence AS QALC_Sequence
FROM dbo.Questionaires AS Questionaires 
INNER JOIN dbo.QuestionaireSections AS QuestionaireSections 
    ON Questionaires.QuestionaireKey = QuestionaireSections.QuestionaireKey 
INNER JOIN dbo.Sections AS Sections 
    ON QuestionaireSections.SectionKey = Sections.SectionKey 
INNER JOIN dbo.SectionQuestions AS SectionQuestions 
    ON Sections.SectionKey = SectionQuestions.SectionKey 
INNER JOIN dbo.Questions AS Questions 
    ON SectionQuestions.QuestionKey = Questions.QuestionKey 
INNER JOIN dbo.QuestionTypes AS QuestionTypes 
    ON Questions.QuestionTypeKey = QuestionTypes.QuestionTypeKey 
INNER JOIN dbo.QuestionAnswerListCodes AS QuestionAnswerListCodes 
    ON Questions.QuestionKey = QuestionAnswerListCodes.QuestionKey 
INNER JOIN dbo.AnswerListCodes AS AnswerListCodes 
    ON QuestionAnswerListCodes.AnswerListCodeKey = AnswerListCodes.AnswerListCodeKey
```

Each Question has possible answers from AnswerListCodes.  I understand vw_Questions entity is read only.  The data that needs to be saved is in the Answers & EvaluationAnswers tables.  My Controller code thus far is:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Answers = db.Answers.ToList();
    ViewBag.EvaluationAnswers = db.EvaluationAnswers.ToList();
    return View(db.vw_Questions.ToList());
}
```

This results in a [display that I'm looking](http://www.3pc.com/images/image.jpg) for are here.

I'm not seeing how to get the selected answers in each dropdownlist back to my controller.  Some answers will be text too.

View code:

```
@model IEnumerable<Prototype_06.Models.vw_Questions>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>


<style>
    table { border-collapse:collapse; }
    table,th, td {border: 1px solid gray; }
</style>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<table>  
    @foreach (var group in (Model.OrderBy(x => x.QAS_Sequence).GroupBy(item => item.SectionName)))
    {
        <tr>
            <th colspan="3">@group.Key</th>
        </tr>
        foreach (var item in group.OrderBy(x => x.SQ_Sequence).GroupBy(subItem => subItem.Question).Distinct()) {
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>@item.Key</td>
                <td>
                   <select> 
                        <option value="@Guid.Empty"></option>
                     @foreach (var ans in item.OrderBy(x => x.QALC_Sequence))
                     {
                        <option value="@ans.AnswerListCodeKey">@ans.AnswerListCodeName</option>

                     }
                    </select>
                </td>
             </tr>
        }
     }
</table>
<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</p>  
 }


@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: So you want once the user make a selection, the controller will know it and return a new view model. I guess?

Comment: Still confused. Once the form is submitted, it will post to the controller action specified in `action` attribute of your form. So, can you please show us the code in your View?

Comment: I think a key part is to find a way to render the dropdownlist in the MVC way.  I'm thinking that will allow the selected results to show in the posted data

Comment: Okay I think you are far from understanding MVC. The view model is not built that way. Please go check a most basic tutorial. It will help you.

Comment: I've looked at many basic examples, they only deal with single tables and I see how those work.  My issue is displaying data from many tables and saving into a table that is not needed in the view for display.

Comment: Personally, I would create the question selectlists and pass them to the view as part of a model.  That way when the form data is posted, you'll have each question as a model property with a corresponding value (the answer)

Comment: Regarding the population of the selectlists, if you're getting all the data in one single db hit, then you can use linq to query the result set and pull out the data you need.

Comment: Do you think I'm wrong to use vw_Questions SQL view? Maybe my ViewModel should be a Linq query that references the data I need? I'm new to Linq so I don't know what that should look like

Answer (score 0):

> My issue is displaying data from many tables and saving into a table that is not needed in the view for display.

These are two separate things. The data you display on page and how you get it has nothing to do with how you receive it or save it back to the database.

Using a view is not a wholly bad idea, but its utility is limited. Primarily, views don't have indexes, so if you intend to issue anything other than a `SELECT *`, your queries will be rather slow. Personally, I've never found a use for a database view in an MVC app. When Entity Framework itself is not good enough or efficient enough, I use stored procedures.

Return the data you need from a stored procedure, and then use that to build your view model for display. For your post action, you can use a different view model, if needed, or even the actual entity you plan to save to, if the the fields can be mapped by the modelbinder (i.e. same field names in your form as those on the entity). If you need to use a view model for post, instead, you can map the posted data from the view model to the entity you're saving either manually or by using a tool like AutoMapper.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the action parameter of the form to whichever action (in whichever controller) you want to process the data. When you submit the form they will be passed to that specified action. It can be done in several ways: Declaring it in the BeginForm statement from the very beginning like in :

```
Html.BeginForm("ProcessAnswers","Questionary",FormMethod.Post,new{id="frmQuestionary"})
```

if the form will always to the same action. If for some reason you need to post to different actions according to certain conditions (that's less common), the action can be changed dynamically in javascript you can set the action to the desired value(preferably just before posting to avoid mistakes ), like in:

```
$('#frmQuestionary').attr('action', vURLOfDesiredAction); //vURLOfDesiredAction must have the proper url value, previously set from server side
```

Now, regarding the action you will post to, it should be able to get the data you send. That also can be done in several ways, (if your not clear about it you should read about how MVC data binding works!). Firs of all you must set the name of the controls that you want to post, the select control you have there has no name, so do something like

```
<select name="AnswerId">
```

(that's considering that in your action you will store that data in a model's field named AnswerId, ot at least that a variable named AnswerId will be the one that receive that value- in case you declare the actions with separated parameters)
 The model that this action will process, not necessarily has to coincide with the one you defined in your previous view to show the data, it must however be the proper one for the data you are sending to it, and when you got the data, well... you save it in whichever tables they should be saved.

Just as @Blaise already commented, I recommend you to read more about the MVC basics